# JSP include with parameters usage

Tags: jsp, parameters

How should I access the `param1` value from the included jsp (`navMenu.jsp`)?

```
<jsp:include page="navMenu.jsp" >
    <jsp:param name="param1" value="menu" />
</jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`${param.param1}` (preferable) or `request.getParameter("param1")`

Comment: shouldn't it be ${param.param1} instead of ${param.menu}?

Comment: How to access the `param1 ` by javascript?

Comment: that's an entirely separate question

Comment: To obtain it in javascript you should: <script>   var a = '${param.x}' </script>